# How to insert when pasting column?

Tags: excel, vba, activex

In a worksheet I would like to copy and paste columns with a button.

It should copy two columns and insert them in the first free column that it can find.

For example it would be F and G. If I press the button again it should do same again and insert in H and I this time.

My VBA code for an Active-X Button:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Columns("D:E").Copy
CommandButton1.TopLeftCell.EntireColumn.Insert
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

What do I change to paste in the first free column.

TopLeftCell is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy After Last Column

- It is assumed that the worksheet is not filtered.

```vb
Sub CopyToRight()
    
    Dim lcCell As Range
    Set lcCell = Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If lcCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Columns("D:E").Copy lcCell.EntireColumn.Offset(, 1)

End Sub
```

- In the following two examples, it is additionally assumed that there are no hidden cells (rows or columns) and that the first row of each worksheet column contains data.

**Copy After Last Column**

```
Sub CopyAfterAll()
    With Columns("D:E")
        .Copy .Worksheet.Cells(1, .Worksheet.Columns.Count) _
            .End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

**Insert After Last Column**

```
Sub InsertAfterAll()
    With Columns("D:E")
        .Copy
        .Worksheet.Cells(1, .Worksheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) _
            .Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

- The result of the following two examples is the same (due to entire columns), yet there is a difference: if you uncomment the `Debug.Print` lines, you will notice that in the *After* procedure the range stays `D:E`, while in the *Before* procedure (probably your requirement) the range becomes `F:G`.

**Insert Right After**

```
Sub InsertRightAfter()
    With Columns("D:E")
        .Copy
        .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Insert
        'Debug.Print .Address(0, 0) 
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**Insert Right Before**

```
Sub InsertRightBefore()
    With Columns("D:E")
        .Copy
        .Insert
        'Debug.Print .Address(0, 0) 
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) Can u tell me what the code would be if i would like to insert it in the same row each time, and move the old row to the right.
So i Insert into D and E, and the data currently in D,E moves it to F,G

Comment: I've added `InsertRightAfter` and `InsertRightBefore`.